# PDF Renderer with PrintDialog

Tags: java, printing, swt, pdfrenderer

Is this possible?

I am getting the directory and filename of a existing PDF document.
   `C:\temp\FileName.pdf`

1. Use PDF Renderer to either view the document or print the document
   I have PDF Renderer included in my Eclipse Project, just not sure how to use it
2. Then use PrintDialog to print out the PDF Document.
   I think that PDF Renderer has to do something to make the PDF document printable

I want have 2 buttons on my form

- View PDF -> opens the pdf document in read only
- Print PDF -> gets the pdf document ready to print then calls PrintDialog to select a local printer and then prints

I am not having much luck finding any PDFRenderer sample code that shows how to open the PDF document in view mode.
I haven't seen code on how to send the PDF Renderer result to a PrintDialog to print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly can implement PDF rendering in your application. The question is, if it is really necessary or not. Since you dindn't specify which library you want to include, I can't help you with the `PDFRenderer`.
However, for purpose of launching an external PDF viewer and how to implement a print button, those API classes are useful:

- [`org.eclipse.swt.program.Program`](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fprogram%2FProgram.html)
- [`org.eclipse.swt.printing.PrintDialog`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fprinting%2FPrintDialog.html)

At least it'll help to (partially) solve your problem.

Comment: The libraries are com.sun.pdfview.PDFFile,
com.sun.pdfview.PDFPage, com.sun.pdfview.PDFRenderer

Comment: Again, correct PDF handling in your application can be difficult. The question [Using sun PDF Renderer to display PDFs with embedded fonts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596126/using-sun-pdf-renderer-to-display-pdfs-with-embedded-fonts) tells that there are problems with embedded fonts. I've read about unpredictable rendering behavior elsewhere. PDFBox is mentioned as alternative. If you want to use the PDF renderer from Sun, you should get familiar with embedding Swing into your SWT application since it uses the Java2D API.